# Using MVC3 and JQuery to dynamically and mantain the DataAnnotations

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem similar to this: [Using MVC and JQuery to dynamically & consistently add values to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939761/using-mvc-and-jquery-to-dynamically-consistently-add-values-to-a-table) , but the difference is:

I have table and I'm cloning the last row (to keep the same format) with:

```
var $tableBody = $('#record').find("tbody");
$trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
$trNew = $trLast.clone();
$trLast.after($trNew);
```

`

The rows are created succesfully, but the validations are binded to the first row (`inputs`, `selects` and `textarea`)

Inspecting the elment, are displayed:

```
<td>
// Code generated with the jquery .clone()
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Es necesario agregar una fecha." id="Salidas_0__Fecha" name="Salidas[1].Fecha" type="datetime" value="" autocomplete="off" class="hasDatepicker input-validation-error">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Salidas[1].Fecha" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</td>
```

But the `field-validation-valid` is not binded to the `input`.
Exist a way to do that?

Comment: What does "the `field-validation-valid` is not binded to the `input`" even mean?  That looks like it's just a `class` added to a `span`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you play with dynamic content, you have to add JQuery Validation to the new content after cloning the row:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("form"));
```

Second, the attribute "data-valmsg-for", on spans with "field-validation-valid" class, must be the same of attribute "name" of his corresponding input in each row of your table.

So, for example, a table with three rows has to look like this:

```
<td>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Es necesario agregar una fecha." id="Salidas_0__Fecha" name="Salidas[0].Fecha" type="datetime" value="" autocomplete="off" class="hasDatepicker input-validation-error">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Salidas[0].Fecha" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</td>
<td>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Es necesario agregar una fecha." id="Salidas_1__Fecha" name="Salidas[1].Fecha" type="datetime" value="" autocomplete="off" class="hasDatepicker input-validation-error">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Salidas[1].Fecha" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</td>
<td>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Es necesario agregar una fecha." id="Salidas_2__Fecha" name="Salidas[2].Fecha" type="datetime" value="" autocomplete="off" class="hasDatepicker input-validation-error">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Salidas[2].Fecha" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</td>
```

And the last is also needed for the correct Model Binding when posting the form.