# Validating Data Annotation using Jquery, not displaying the error message

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, data-annotations

I have a model property who's value can be required or not required on the view based on the value of another property. I have implemented it in the view as follows.

```
<input @Html.Raw(Model.IsRequired ? "required data-val=true' data-val-required='" + Model.Name + " selection is required.'" : "") asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
if (Model.IsRequired)
{
    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
}
```

As indicated based on the Required field value, the validation is applied or not applied.

I also had to add this bit of code.

```
$("#btnSubmit").on("click", function () {
    $("#form").submit();
});
```

The code works fine in validation of the code, however the message does not get displayed. What am I missing?

I also tried using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35874345/7793375) and changed my validation span to as below, but it did not work either.

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Comment: You don't need to add these attributes. They are added by the tag helper when you use `asp-for`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I do not add the Required validation on the server side; so does it work even then?

Comment: @ChrisPratt Removing all the attributes and just the asp-for on the view still does not display the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to add Data Annotations for validation.Here is a simple workaound like below:

1.Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
}
```

2.View(You need to change your `@Html.Raw()` and be sure you have added`@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}`):

```
@model TestModel
<form id="form">
    <input @Html.Raw(Model.IsRequired ? "data-val='true' data-val-required='selection is required.'" : "") id="Name" name="Name" type="text" class="input-validation-error" />
    @if (Model.IsRequired)
    {
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    }

    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" />
</form>

@section Scripts{
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

3.Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var test = new TestModel() { IsRequired = true };
    return View(test);
}
```

4.Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This works as required. However you might need to remove class="input-validation-error". It seems to load the screen with a red border already instead of doing it on button click.